# Activity Life cycle Stroring and Restoring

Tags: android

"saving the all data using onSavedInstanceState(Bundle) but if my app is closed then reopened my apps and how to restore the saved Instance  "

```
package com.example.savedandrestored;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText first,last;
Button submit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    first=findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    last=findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    submit=findViewById(R.id.submit);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("firstName") && savedInstanceState.containsKey("lastName")) {
        first.setText(savedInstanceState.get("firstName").toString());
        last.setText(savedInstanceState.get("lastName").toString());
    }
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
 savedInstanceState.putString("firstName",first.getText().toString());
   savedInstanceState.putString("lastName",last.getText().toString());
            onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
    });
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     }
}
```

"it does not restore the data when I open the apps and no new data is executed"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an Android Activity state using save instance state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Comment: You cannot restore the current data of activities or fragments when close and reopen the app unless you save it to the database or shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

`onSaveInstanceState` is used for another purpose like recreating activity in rotation or etc.

> saving all data using onSavedInstanceState(Bundle) but if my app
>   is closed then reopened my apps

Then you should read the [lifecycle of an activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

But the short answer to your question is

1. Save your data inside `onPause`
2. Retrieve it `onResume`

Like an example

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //retrieve your data here and update UI here not onCreate 

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //Save your data here into shared prefs, or file, or DB (*last not recommended)
    }
}
```

Comment: if i closed the apps or swipe in recent apps then reopen the apps old data file(SAVED INSTANCE STATE) is executed or not

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) please refer here

Comment: If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause()

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: Does it help you? if yes then consider accepting, ask for clarification otherwise